# Where is setSelectedRow() for JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, row, selection

Java Swing JTable has a `getSelectedRow()` method, but does not have a `setSelectedRow()` method.

I need to highlight/select a row in a JTable. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
ListSelectionModel selectionModel = 
  table.getSelectionModel();
selectionModel.setSelectionInterval(start, end);
```

Answer (score 17):

haha, the eternal question - and neither Howard nor Cris found the direct cover methods :-)

```
table.setRowSelectionInterval(first, last)
table.addRowSelectionInterval(first, last)
```

Answer (score 7):

It is provided via the SelectionModel

```
table.getSelectionModel().setSelectionInterval(int index0, int index1)
```

Comment: Had to choose one of you to approve the answer. I supported the newbie and voted up both answers.